# Have street address, need geocoordinates using Python and geopy

Tags: python-3.x, geolocation, geopy

I have a data set of street addresses and need to determine if they are within certain lat/long coordinates. Since I'm using Python, geopy seems like a common way to go.

But geopy is not a geolocation service, it's "just a library which provides these implementations for many different services". So I see two options:

1. Use geopy with Nominatim, which is free but you get only one request per second (it's slow)

   from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

or

2. Use geopy (or not) with a paid service that is faster, such as Google, PickPoint, or something else.

Do I have the correct understanding? (are there any fast free options?)

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to accomplish this.

The most common is to use **GoogleCloud** service (it is indeed free but demands a bank card) & the package `googlemaps`

```
import googlemaps

gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='Add Your Key here')

# Geocoding an address
geocode_result = gmaps.geocode('1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA')

#Here you can process your result at your leisure
lat, lon = geocode_result.geometry.location.values()
```

But there is a lot of projects without necessity to give your bank personal information, such as `geocoder`. It can use the whole list of geocoding services. For example, ArcGis is free & fast enough (not a request per second)

```
import geocoder

result = geocoder.arcgis(location="Regency Run, San Antonio, Texas")
if result.ok:
    lat, lon = result.latlng
else:
    raise Exception("I have gotten a bad result :-(")
```

The presence of point inside perimeter you can define, for instance, with `geopandas`

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely import Point

gpd.io.file.fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers['KML'] = 'rw'

some_map = gpd.read_file(fr'some_map.kml', driver='KML')
some_map.contains(Point(lon, lat)).values
```

P. S. There is a slight trick you could use. Parallel your requests & use several services simultaneously (ArcGis, Google, Yandex &c.). The results are not consistent strictly but maybe it is not a problem for your task with several millions addresses.

Comment: Hi! Is there a way to do 10,000 street addresses with module `geopy`? (Because of the company internet settings, I am not able to use other convenient module.)

Comment: @June It can use Google Cloud which is free (at least if we talk about just geocoding). So you just need a bank card to sign up. It can process a lot of addresses per second. I do not remember precisely but my dataset with hundred thousands of records took less than a minute. There could be problems only if you work in North Korea, Russia, Iran, or somewhere akin.

Comment: Hi @Vovin, thank you for the reply! I am using the company network and would be put into production. Putting my personal bank card in the company's production pipeline is not allowed. Is there a way to work around with it? (I also find geopandas and many other modules not available in the company's network. That's why I am sticking to geopy)

Comment: @June Check [geocoders list](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#module-geopy.geocoders), there is, for instance, ArcGIS. It is fast enough, free & do not require API keys. In my case, I registered Google Cloud account for my company with their bank account & they gave me the restricted API key.